# Is there a way to write this code more general and elegant?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a bit of a newbie in Python and wanted to ask, if there's a way to write this code more elegant and general:

```
array = np.linalg.norm(np.array([
   X-mu[0],
   X-mu[1],
   X-mu[2],
   X-mu[3],
   X-mu[4],
]), axis=2)
```

X is an RGB-Image (NxD, 300000x3 array), mu is a kxD (5x3) matrix. Ultimately, array should be a kxN, or Nxk matrix.

Is there a way to loop over the indeces of mu instead of manually typing it?

Comment: What size is `X`?

Comment: X is a NxD (ca. 300.000x3 array)

Comment: What size do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Wait, X is 2D or 3D?

Comment: just updated the description. X is 2D.

Comment: Your current result doesn't match your expectation. Subtraction doesn't involve reduction.

Comment: It actually does: mu[0] is a 1x3 array minus each entry of X and doing that with each row (5) of mu, leads to Nx5x3. Then applying L2-norm, leads to Nx5.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the norm is a reduction. I was too focused on the argument.

Comment: no problem! :) The actual code (k-means clustering) is working. However, I find it not elegant enough and was thinking, there must be a better solution out there...

Comment: I'll post a solution when I get to a desktop. Couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to perform a subtraction operation on a `(3k, 3)` and `(5, 3)` array. To be able to reduce the second axis for a final result of `(3k, 5)` or `(5, 3k)`, you need the first dimensions to broadcast together. This is trivial with broadcasting if you introduce a new axis:

```
np.linalg.norm(X[:, None, :] - mu[None, ...], axis=-1)
```

OR

```
np.linalg.norm(X[None, ...] - mu[:, None, :], axis=-1)
```

`None` creates a new axis of size 1 in the location it's placed in the subscript. An ellipsis (`...`) grabs the remaining axes so you don't have to write `:, :` explicitly.

The difference in the expressions above broadcasts to `(3k, 5, 3)` and `(5, 3k, 3)`, respectively. In both cases, `norm` reduces the last axis, leaving the first two elements of the shape. Depending on your memory layout, either approach may be faster, sometimes noticeably. It's probably worth doing a benchmark if that matters to you.